# Discord.js v13 "cannot send empty message" when it is not

Tags: javascript, discord.js

*Objective:* Making a **simon says command**

*Problem:*
I am receiving a strange error while `sending an non-empty message` in discord.js v13.
For some reason the discord api sends the message:

```js
const startMessage = await channel.send({ content: `Quest: **${start.string} ${currentGame.startMessage.toLowerCase()}** *(You have ${Math.floor(actualTime / 1000)} seconds)*`})`
```

and then returns an error:

```js
DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
```

|--**NOTE:** ------------------------------------------------------------------|

This seems to only happend when I put an `await` before the

`channel.send(message)` command

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------|

And it doesn't make sense why it sends the message and after that returns an error about that specific message.

```js
module.exports.runGame = async function (channel, players_, client) {
    let players = players_
    let time = 1
    let winners
    let gameOn = true
    let rounds = 1
    let lastGame = null
    //example of how to start a game
    let config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`./guilds/${channel.guild.id}.json`)); //for this game only

    while (gameOn) {

        //chooses a random minigame
        
        let enabledGames = []
        for(let game of minigames){
            if(config.minigames[game.name]){
                if(game.name == 'oppositeDay' && rounds < 4) continue
                enabledGames.push(game)
            }
        }

        if(enabledGames.length == 0){
            channel.send('You need to have at least one game enabled to play. Enable/disable with the config command.')
            return
        }
        let currentGame  = enabledGames[getRandomInt(enabledGames.length)]
        
        while(currentGame == lastGame){
            currentGame = enabledGames[getRandomInt(enabledGames.length)]
        }
        
        //picks a random start of startmessage (67% chance of getting "Simon says")
        let start

        if (currentGame.name == 'oppositeDay') {
            start = {
                string: config.opposite_day ? 'Good morning,' : 'Simon says',
                real: true
            }
        } else if(rounds < 3){
            start = {
                string: 'Simon says',
                real: true
            } 
        } else {
            start = randomStart(channel.guild.id, config)
        }
        let actualTime = (time * currentGame.defTime).clamp(5000, 15000)
        //sends startmessage
        console.log("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nSTART\n\n\n\n\n");

        try {
            const startMessage = await channel.send({ content: `Quest: **${start.string} ${currentGame.startMessage.toLowerCase()}** *(You have ${Math.floor(actualTime / 1000)} seconds)*`})
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(`Known Error in line 59 on game.js ${err}`)        
        }


        //runs the game
        console.log("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nEND\n\n\n\n\n");
        console.log(currentGame.name)
        
        let {
            playersOut,
            playersLeft,
            configOut
        } = await currentGame.run(channel, players, actualTime, client, {
            simonSaid: start.real,
            startMessage: startMessage,
            config: config
        })
        config = configOut

    }
}
```

Here is the full error output including my *debug* `console.log(); instructions`

```js
START





/home/lixt/Desktop/The Lixt Bot/LIXTON/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:298
      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
    at RequestHandler.execute (/home/lixt/Desktop/The Lixt Bot/LIXTON/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:298:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (/home/lixt/Desktop/The Lixt Bot/LIXTON/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:50:14)
    at async TextChannel.send (/home/lixt/Desktop/The Lixt Bot/LIXTON/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/interfaces/TextBasedChannel.js:171:15) {
  method: 'post',
  path: '/channels/997996030572384288/messages',
  code: 50006,
  httpStatus: 400,
  requestData: {
    json: {
      content: undefined,
      tts: false,
      nonce: undefined,
      embeds: undefined,
      components: undefined,
      username: undefined,
      avatar_url: undefined,
      allowed_mentions: undefined,
      flags: undefined,
      message_reference: undefined,
      attachments: undefined,
      sticker_ids: undefined
    },
    files: []
  }
}
```

**How do I know the error is in that specific message?**

I debug it to there. I made a `console.log()` before the message and other `console.log` after that message.

## Edit

Using vsc debugger I got this image [image]

Comment: content is for embeds not messages. Just use `const startMessage = await channel.send(\`Quest: **${start.string} ${currentGame.startMessage.toLowerCase()}** *(You have ${Math.floor(actualTime / 1000)} seconds)*\`})`

Comment: are you sure it's not trying to send another message? everything looks fine and discord.js is 100% promise-based so the error definitely has nothing to do with the await...

Comment: I am sure I have checked every line of code in my project.